# Which template loaders is Django using?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In [documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) to `cached Loader` is written

> This loader is automatically enabled if OPTIONS['loaders'] isn’t
>   specified and OPTIONS['debug'] is False

How to confirm that Django is really using cached Loader? How to check which template loaders is Django using?

Comment: Did you specify the `loaders` option? If not, and you're in production (`DEBUG` is `False`) then it's as the documentation says. You can check Django's source code if you don't trust the documentation, but I don't really understand what specific issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Here's the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/template/engine.py#L27). If you override `loaders` then it's using whichever loader you specified.

Comment: `loaders` are no specified and `DEBUG` is false. I trust the documenation but maybe I made mistake somewhere. I suspect cached Loader is not used on my server even thou the documentation says so. I want to check somehow which class instances of Loaders does Django use on my server.

Comment: Why are you suspecting the cached loader isn't used? It's used, look at the django source code. You can be certain of that. You can also just open up a shell on your production environment and type `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.TEMPLATES['OPTIONS'].get('loaders'))` to check that the settings aren't changed somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will show you the current loaders that are used by Django:

```
from django.template.engine import Engine
engine = Engine.get_default()
print(engine.loaders)
```